# Google Maps API InfoWindow should be open by default

Tags: google-maps

I am try the Google Maps API and run into a little problem. Look at this example below. I want to have a Infobox open when I go to the site (not like in this example from google that it is cloesed and triggered by an click event). How to manage this? Maybe this is a beginners question to a Google Maps Api pro^^

```
>  function initialize() {
>     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
>     var myOptions = {
>       zoom: 4,
>       center: myLatlng,
>       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
>     }
>  
>     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
>  
>     var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
>         '<div id="siteNotice">'+
          'hello world</div>'+
>         '</div>';
>         
>     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
>         content: contentString
>     });
>  
>     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
>         position: myLatlng,
>         map: map,
>         title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
>     });
>     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
>       infowindow.open(map,marker);
>     });   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `infowindow.open(map,marker);` to the end of your `initialize()` function:

```
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
        'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
        'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
        'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
        '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
        'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
        'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
        'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
        'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
        'Heritage Site.</p>'+
        '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
        'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
        '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  }
```